# Attribute equals selector not working ("input[name='name']")

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to implement this kind of jQuery selector to my code, but it's not working for some reason I don't understand. This is similar to the [jQuery example here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="orderDetails" />
```

and the query is:

```
var nameFieldContent = $('.orderDetails input[name="name"]');
console.log(nameFieldContent);
```

console.log doesn't show any matching elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is wrong because the class as well as the name attribute belongs to the same element, but you have used a descendant relationship in your selector.

```
var nameFieldContent = $('input[name="name"].orderDetails');
```

Your selector looks for an input element with name `name` which is inside an element with class `orderDetails` like `<div class="orderDetails"><input type="text" name="name" /></div>`

Answer (score 3):

Try to change your selector like below,

```
 $('input[name=name].orderDetails');
```

What your selector would do is,

```
$('.orderDetails input[name="name"]');
// --------------^  Search for descendant elements inside .orderDetails
```

---

**Special Note:** You don't need to wrap the attribute's value inside quotes since its value contains of a single word.

Answer (score 3):

Class name and input are same level .so you should not use space b/w class and input.if it is used that like descendant selector

```
$('input.orderDetails[name="name"]');
```

Comment: Corrected the spelling of `descendant`

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
 $('input[name="name"].orderDetails');
```